# Regex not returning all matches in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find all the matches in a string that follow a particular pattern like this `{{any thing here}}`, but I'm not able to extract all the matches properly. Don't know what I'm doing wrong. Below is the code that I have tried so far.

```js
const string = `You have been identified in <span class="alert underline">{{db.count}}</span> breaches with <span class="alert underline">{{db.data_types}}</span> unique data types.`;
```

**I have tried the following methods:**

**Method 1**

```js
const matches = /{{(.*?)}}/igm.exec(value);
console.log(matches);
```

**Output:**

```js
{
    0: "{{db.count}}",
    1: "db.count",
    index: 58,
    input: "You have been identified in <span class="alert und…line">{{db.data_types}}</span> unique data types.",
    groups: undefined
}
```

**Method 2**

```js
const matches = RegExp('{{(.*?)}}', 'igm').exec(value);
console.log(matches);
```

**Output:**

```js
{
    0: "{{db.count}}",
    1: "db.count",
    index: 58,
    input: "You have been identified in <span class="alert und…line">{{db.data_types}}</span> unique data types.",
    groups: undefined
}
```

**Method 3**

```js
const matches = value.match(/{{(.*?)}}/igm);
console.log(matches);
```

**Output:**

```js
[
    "{{db.count}}",
    "{{db.data_types}}"
]
```

**Expected output:**

```js
[
    'db.count',
    'db.data_types'
]
```

If anyone has faced the same issue, please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to repeatedly apply `exec` to get all of the matches, as demonstrated in the RegExp docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find all matches, you'll have to use exec() in a loop.

Example:

```js
const string = `You have been identified in <span class="alert underline">{{db.count}}</span> breaches with <span class="alert underline">{{db.data_types}}</span> unique data types.`;

let regEx = /{{(.*?)}}/igm;
let result;

while ((result = regEx.exec(string)) !== null) {
    console.log(result[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, It helped me too.

Answer (score 0):

Your method 3 looks good. I would try this regex to not-match the curly braces:

```
[^{}]+(?=}})
```

Comment: It's not efficient, It's adding extra array elements, here's the response ```["leaked_databases.breach_count", "", "leaked_databases.data_types_count", ""]```

Comment: You're right, I updated the answer to use a better quantifier (`+`: one or more non-curly brace).

Answer (score 0):

Grouping does not play well with the /g (global) flag, [See here](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#contents-of-parentheses). @fragezeichen gave the right solution (also documented in the link)